# How to sort this JSON

Tags: iphone, json

How to sort this json. The json below is output in browser.

```
{
event: {
July: [
{
createdSeatMap: "yes",
status: "1",
completed: "1",
eventPayment: "0",
}
],
Aug: [
{
createdSeatMap: "yes",
status: "1",
completed: "1",
eventPayment: "0",
}
],
Sept: [ ],
Oct: [ ],
Nov: [ ],
Dec: [
{
createdSeatMap: "yes",
status: "1",
completed: "1",
eventPayment: "0",
stamp: "1386019800"
},
{
createdSeatMap: "yes",
status: "1",
completed: "1",
eventPayment: "0",
stamp: "1387921620"
}
],
Jan: [ ],
Feb: [ ],
Mar: [ ], 
Apr: [ ],
May: [ ],
June: [ ]
}
}
```

Below is in console when fetched.

```
 Apr =     (
);
Aug =     (
            {

        createdSeatMap: "yes",
        status: "1",
        completed: "1",
        eventPayment: "0",
    }
);
Dec =     (
           {
createdSeatMap: "yes",
status: "1",
completed: "1",
eventPayment: "0",
stamp: "1386019800"
},
{
createdSeatMap: "yes",
status: "1",
completed: "1",
eventPayment: "0",
stamp: "1387921620"
}
);
Feb =     (
);
Jan =     (
);
July =     (
            {
        createdSeatMap: "yes",
status: "1",
completed: "1",
eventPayment: "0",
    }
);
June =     (
);
Mar =     (
);
May =     (
);
Nov =     (
);
Oct =     (
);
Sept =     (
);
```

Below is code i am using

```
NSMutableArray *dictAllValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableDictionary *getDataDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

getDataDict = [self.mGetDataDict valueForKey:@"event"];

NSArray *dictAllKeys = [[NSArray alloc] init];

dictAllKeys = [getDataDict allKeys];

NSLog(@"dict :%d", [dictAllKeys count]);
for(int i=0; i<[getDataDict count]; i++)
{
    NSString *strKey = [dictAllKeys objectAtIndex:i];
    [dictAllValues addObjectsFromArray:[getDataDict valueForKey:strKey]];
    if(i==0)
    {

        NSArray *cVals = [dictAllValues valueForKey:strKey];
        int c = [cVals count];
        NSLog(@"values:%@", cVals);
        NSLog(@"values:%@", dictAllValues);
        [self.mArrMOneEvents addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", c]];
        self.mArrMOneEtType = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"type"];
        self.mArrMOneEtTime = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"time"];
        self.mArrMOneEtSeatMap = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"createdSeatMap"];
        self.mArrMOneEtSeatId = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"seatMapId"];
        self.mArrMOneEtQuant = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"quantity"];
        self.mArrMOneEvents = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"eventName"];
        self.mArrMOneETLoc = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"location"];
        self.mArrMOneEtEId = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"id"];
        self.mArrMOneEtDesc = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"description"];
        self.mArrMOneEtDate = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"date"];
        self.mArrMOneEtCurr = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"currency"];
        self.mArrMOneEtCost = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"cost"];
        self.mArrMOneEtCateg = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"category"];
        self.mArrmOneEtImg = [dictAllValues valueForKey:@"banner"];
        NSLog(@"array one:%d", [self.mArrMOneEvents count]);
    }
}

+(NSString *)sendRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request
{
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *responseData;
responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if(responseData && [responseData length]) {
    NSString* aStr;
    aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    return aStr;
}
else {
    return @"No Record Found";
}    
}

+(NSMutableDictionary *)forgotPassw:(NSDictionary *)mailId
{
NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myvnt.co/api2/forgotpassword/%@",[mailId valueForKey:@"mailId"]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                [NSURL URLWithString:
                                 [urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                                  NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];

NSString *responseString = [MtApi sendRequest:request];
NSLog(@"response:%@", responseString);
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:results];
NSLog(@"dict in API-------------%@",dict);

return dict;
}
```

How to sort this please guide for above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found a question previsouly posted, hope this can help you. [json arrays and sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601229/json-arrays-and-sorting)

Answer (score 1):

JSON is esentially an NSDictionary, which is not an ordered collection. To have a consistent ordering you will need to print manually:

```
NSArray sortedKeys = [json keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(someSelectorWhichSortsByMonthOrder)];

[sortedKeys enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *month, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    NSLog(@"%@ = %@", month, json[month]);
}];
```

but having said that, the order isnt changing the contents of the dictionary, so is there any reason you really care how it looks printed on the console?

edit: since you want the ordering for a table view this is what I would do:

dont bother with the sorting above, just define an array which contains the names of the months (in order). In cellForRowAtIndexPath: get the current month using indexPath.row and then you can access the month data by calling:

```
NSString *cellMonth = self.orderedMonthNames[indexPath.row];
NSDictionary *monthData = self.jsonDictionary[cellMonth];
```

Comment: It is saying no selector available for someSelectorWhichSortsByMonthOrder. I have posted my code also pls check.

Comment: obviously you will need to decide which selector you use there, i dont know which selector will order based on month, you will probably have to write a method

Comment: Yes i need to care about order because i am showing months in table view it start from current month so values need to be in order to show in their respective months.

Comment: in that case I dont think you need to bother with sorting, take a look at my edit

Comment: It is not applicable here man because the code i posted above sorts gets data and then serve to arrays than display data in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Can you please relate the code with above mentioned code.

Comment: The edit will do that, you need to make a new array, and save the dictionary so you can lookup the month

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33248/discussion-between-wattson12-and-iphone-6)